# Vue-Router Passing Data with Props

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, axios, vue-router

I am having a hard time passing props using Vue-Router. I seem to not be able to access the props when I bring them into the next view. This is my methods object:

```
methods: {
    submitForm() {
      let self = this;
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: url_here,
        data:{
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        },
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
        }
      }).then(function(response) {
        self.userInfo = response.data;
        self.$router.push({name: 'reading-comprehension', props: {GUID:self.userInfo.uniqueID }});
      })
   }
}
```

The post request is working, but when I try to route to a new component and pass in a props to access in the next component, it says,

> Property or method "guid" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data
>   properties in the data option.

By the way, the component that I am routing to looks like this:

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="grid-container" id="read-comp">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>Make a sentence:</h1>
      {{ GUID }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data(){
   return {
     props: ['GUID'],
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

When you navigate to the new route programmatically, you should [use `params`, not props](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html).

```
self.$router.push({name: 'reading-comprehension', params: {guid:self.userInfo.uniqueID }});
```

Secondly, in your route definition, you should set [the `props` property](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html) to true.

```
{name: "reading-comprehension", component: SomeComponent, props: true }
```

Finally, in your component, you define `props` separately from `data` and it should be all lower case.

```
export default {
 props: ["guid"],
 data(){
   return {
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it! This worked. Thanks...I am super new to Vue.

Comment: thanks it did worked.. wasted so much time.. finally got

Comment: This is a really great answer - concise and right to the point, and providing clear solution code.

Comment: does the value have to be scalar? can I pass an object?

Comment: @Ayyash You can pass an object.